# pure C generic bidirectional hashtable with specific requirements

Tags: c, data-structures, hash, struct, hashtable

I have to design and implement a data-structure, which is like `bimap`, `bidimap` or `dualmap`, i.e. hashtable in which values can be used to extract keys and of course in reverse direction.

Normally, it can be implemented on top of two independent hashtables, but there are some specific requirements:

1. minimal memory allocations during operation (better to allocate all memory at start up only)
2. share same data (if implemented as two hashtables)
3. upper bound of number of entries is known
4. keys and values can be any data structures (generic), but length is fixed at start up
5. only C, no STL, from scratch
6. supports remove operations

What I have so far is:

```
typedef struct HashTable {
    int key_len;
    int data_len;
    int num_buckets;
    HashEntry *buckets;
} HashTable;

typedef struct HashEntry {
    void* key; 
    void* data;
    HashEntry* next; //list for collision resolution
} HashEntry;

HashTable* createHashTable (int max_capacity, int num_buckets, int key_len, int data_len);
```

So the plan is create two hashtables, each being an array of buckets.

In each bucket preallocate list of entries of length `max_capacity / num_buckets`

Then to allocate byte array to share data and serve as memory pool:

`char* p = malloc((key_len+data_len) * max_capacity)`;

then put function would put key and data into byte array and both hashtables would assign `key` and `data` pointers accordingly.

The main challenges come from

1. collisions (more than expected number in a bucket, it would require additional allocations)
2. remove operation and management of the memory pool

**How would you improve design to address these challenges?**

Comment: Can you ensure that *both* the key and the value are unique (and the mapping is a bijection) or can several keys point to the same value, or one key point to multiple values (but the *combination* of {key,value} is still unique) ? In both cases: what would you want to happen when a duplicate is detected?

Comment: @wildplasser, keys and values are unique.

Comment: BTW: you need two versions of the `buckets` array, plus two `->next` pointers in the `HashRntries` ; both keys and values need their own tablehead and table chains. 2) if key and data are fixed size, you can store them in one big array (like the `*p` array in the question), or even inside the HashEntries. No need for pointers here. 3) the same for the next-pointers; since you know that the size is fixed, you can use indexes instead of pointers. The indexes will be bounded by the table size, and could be 16 or even 8 bits wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Collision resolution

I don't think that the collisions are really going to require additional allocation operations if you set it up correctly.  Allocate the maximum RAM that you are going to be able to use. Set up your buckets with some flag bits to do accounting. You can borrow from the schemes that inodes use; link in a new unused bucket as a daughter where you have large hash collisions.

#### Considerations

If somehow your keys are such that your data gets a lot of hash collisions or your distribution is lop-sided, because a few keys get used a lot, you may end up having to defrag for your tables along the way. But this is simply rewriting of the data at a much longer interval than use of the device.

### Removal of memory management.

You will have to do pointer and boundary accounting but that's about it. This isn't a new problem. Filesystems do this all the time.

Comment: Can you suggest more about memory management? If I need to remove some entries, it means some chunks in pre-allocated memory can be reused. So I need to keep track of that. I have read about free-list which seems to be good for fixed size chunks. But list itself requires dynamic memory.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: Since your sizes and the count of elements is fixed, you can just pre-allocate one (count * (keysize+valueside)) big chunk of memory, and put your payload there. No need for freelists, every node owns its own subchunk of this.